# cytoscape.js How to remove the grey circle when panning

Tags: cytoscape.js

i use cytoscape.js. to draw Node Graphs
if i pan the Graph with Mouse, there is a grey circle on my mouse position.
I have no Idea how to remove this.
Can you help me please?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Only Overwrite the Core style for remove grey circle:

```
.selector('core') // just core properties
.css({
  'active-bg-size': 0
})
```

Comment: Does this work? I've tried like: `this.cy.style().selector('core').css({'active-bg-size':0})` . Though it works, it gives me a compile error.

Comment: or like the form in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58231913/what-is-a-proper-way-to-remove-the-gray-circle-on-panning-the-graph-in-cytoscape)

Answer (score 2):

How about centering the arrow on the active background indicator. Right now there is a small padding (arrow slightly decentered) which causes improper click on edges. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the active state on the background, indicated by the semitransparent circle around the cursor (or your finger on touch).  For reasons of consistency across platforms and providing feedback to the user, this feature is not disableable.  What we could do simply is allow the active area to be styled so you could effectively hide it. -M  https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/337

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i found a solution. There are styleattributes for 'core', active-bg-color and active-bg-opacity. These are the styles for this active state.

Comment: Great.  The ticket is there because I couldn't find it written down in the docs.  Thanks again -M

Comment: I've tried like: `this.cy.style().selector('core').css({'active-bg-size':0})`. Though it works, it gives me a compile error.