# What is a proper way to remove the gray circle on panning the graph in cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I've looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18561879/7289627) and tried like,

```
style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
  {
    selector: 'core',
    style: {
      'active-bg-size': 0
    }
},
```

on initializing the `cy` instance. Though it works, it gives me a compile error so I'm wondering if there's a proper or recommended way to achieve this. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi there, you could always ask this under the mentioned post, so that @maxkfranz sees the question. This is almost a duplicate to the old question, therefore please use the comments for this.

Comment: I think it is because you have `'active-bg-size'` under `style`, whereas in the linked question it is under `.css`